# how to pass login cookies to all requests made by rules

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm writting a scrapy CrawlSpider to scrape data from instagram.com  .
I wanna have the rules to use cookies . but I don't know how ! could you please help me?
I mean that all the requests that are downloaded to be sent to mypars function should use the cookies . 
with lots of thanks.

Comment: Can you post your workings by far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `process_request` in your rule for processing your request object like:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('XPATHS')), process_request='set_cookie', follow=True),
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('XPATHS')), callback='parse_product', process_request='set_cookie', follow=True)
)


def set_cookie(self, request):
    return request.replace(headers={'cookie': 'Add cookies here'})
```

`process_request` is a function where you can process your requests. Here it is `set_cookie`

Comment: Dear AnD lots  of thanks for your comment . I'll try that and tell if it worked . :)